# android/gradle 3.2.1 exclude file not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to exclude specific file by product Flavor.

but exclude is not working

here is my `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "library"
    productFlavors {
        favor1 {
            dimension "library"
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    sourceSets {
        favor1 {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java {
                exclude '**/toExcludeFile.java'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

}
```

I change Build Variants to flavor1Release
and I build project.

but `"toExcludeFile.java"` exist in generated aar file.

gradle version: 3.2.1
android studio version: 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give the full path for your file to be excluded. Something like this:

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {

        favor1 {

            java {
                // change according to your file path.
                exclude 'com/package/app/toExcludeFile.java'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```